# Looking for ways to aggregate info/data from different websites

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, cross-domain, aggregate

I'm a fresh-out-of-college programmer with some experience in Python and Javascript, and I'm trying to develop either a website or just a back-end system that will aggregate information from online market websites which don't have any API (or none that I've found, anyway). Ideally I would also want the system that can write to local storage to track changes to the data over time in some kind of database, but that's down the road a bit.

I've already pounded out some javascript that can grab the data I want, but apparently there doesn't seem to be a way to access or act upon data from other websites due to data security protections or to save the data to local storage in order to be read from other pages. I know that there are ways to aggregate data, as I've seen other websites that do this.

I can load websites in Python using the urllib2 and use regular expressions to parse what I want from some pages, but on a couple of the desired sites I would need to log into the website before I can access the data I want to gather.

Since I am relatively new to programming, is there an ideal tool / programming language that would streamline or simplify what I'm trying to do?

If not, could you please point me in the right direction for how I might go about this? After doing some searching, there seems to be a general lack of cross-domain data gathering and aggregation. Maybe I'm not even using the right terminology to describe what I'm trying to do.

Whichever way you would look at this, please help! :-)

Comment: Selenium Webdriver is a good tool for automating logins and manipulating websites that don't have API's

Comment: I had looked at Selenium Webdriver about an hour ago, and while that might work, it looks like I would need to have a separate instance of each webpage doing the specific things, each saving to individual files, and then have an additional program to aggregate the information which seems like a lot.

I was hoping to have a single program that can reach out to the different sites and act on it all at once... but that might not be how the tools available work.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use selenium webdriver to login to get cookie,and use requests library to scrap the message.That is what my company do in the scraping system.if you only use selenium webdriver, you will need to many memory and cpu capacity.
if you are good at html and js,it is  a good way for you to use requests library to Simulate logging.
for the website you must log in,the most import thing is to get cookie.

Comment: I'm not quite sure which 'requests library' you're referring to. Is this a library provided with Selenium Webdriver, JS or Python?

Comment: it is a library provided by python